# A Boolean recursive function to tell if a digit appears in an integer an even number of times

Tags: recursion

The function gets an integer and a digit, and should return true
if the digit appears an even number of times in the integer, or false if not.

For example:

If `digit=1` and `num=1125`
the function should return `true`.

If `digit=1` and `num=1234`
the function should return `false`.

```
bool isEven(int num, int dig)
{
    bool even;

    if (num < 10)
        even = false;
    else
    {
        even = isEven(num/10,dig);
```

This is what I've got so far, and I'm stuck...
This is homework so please don't write the answer but hint me and help me get to it by myself.

Comment: sigh... couldn't figure out how to edit the code properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up recursion, you need to figure out two things:

1. **The base case.** What is are the easy cases that you can handle outright? For example, can you handle single-digit numbers easily?
2. **The rule(s) that reduce all other cases towards the base case.** For example, can you chop off the last digit and somehow transform the solution for the remaning partial number into the solution for the full number?

I can see from your code that you've made some progress on both of these points. However, both are incomplete. For one thing, you are never using the target digit in your code.

Comment: I can't understand if I should count the number of appearances and in the end decide if it's an even number or not, or have the Boolean variable change it's value every time the function recognize the digit

Comment: Either way could be made to work. Do whatever you think is easier to get right.

Answer (score 1):

The expression num%10 will give you the last digit of a number, which should help.

Your base case is incorrect because a single digit can have an even number of matches (zero is an even number).  Your recursive case also needs work because you need to invert the answer for each match.

Comment: 0 is not a valid input because the integer must be a natural number (an we exclude 0 from the naturals)

Comment: You did not understand.  I was referring to zero as a potential number of matches, not an input.  For example: num=1234, dig=5.  Dig appears zero times, which is even.

Answer (score 0):

This funtion **isEven()** takes a single integer and returns the true if the number of occurence of **numberToCheck** is even.

You can change the **base** as well as the **numberToCheck** which are defined globally.

```
 #include <iostream>



using  std::cout;
using  std::endl;

//  using 10 due to decimal [change it to respective base]
const int  base = 10;
const int  numberToCheck = 5;

//Checks if the number of occurence of "numberToCheck" are even or odd
bool isEven(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    bool hasNumber = false;
    int currentDigit = n % base;
    n /= base;

    
    if (currentDigit == numberToCheck)
        hasNumber = true;

    bool flag = isEven(n);

    // XOR GATE
    return ((!hasNumber) && (flag) || (hasNumber) && (!flag));
};

int main(void)
{

    // This is the input to the funtion IsEven()
    int n = 51515;



    if (isEven(n))
        cout << "Even";
    else
        cout << "Odd";

    return 0;
}
```

> Using XOR Logic to integrate all returns

```
// XOR GATE
    return ((!hasNumber) && (flag) || (hasNumber) && (!flag));
```